# Insufficient Storage Available

Tags: nexus-4, storage, insufficient-memory

I have a Nexus 4. Whenever I try to install *any* app, no matter how small, it says "Insufficient Storage Available".

I have aggressively deleted photos, uninstalled apps, cleared the app cache, and now I have 315 MB free (according to Settings > Storage).

But it *still* says "Insufficient Storage Available" when installing from the Play store. (For *any* app; I have tried with dozens.)

*I cannot even install the apps that I removed two minutes before.* (WTF?) I have restarted several times.

What can I do to fix this erroneous error?

(Note: I don't have any SD card.)

Comment: I've just added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question. You might wish to consult [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mentioned it's a rooted device or not.

When I face similar issues I manage to fix this issue in this way. This is a permission related issue. I guess you face this issue when you're trying to update or install previously uninstalled apps.

When you are uninstalling app, it remain some leftovers in "data/app-lib" directory. Therefore, carefully check app that you wish to install leftovers are in this folder and delete those folders.

- Go to "*/data/app-lib/APP-PATH(that has this error)/lib*" and delete its all the sub folders. Then delete *APP-PATH* folder.

If its not work you can factory rest your device to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I get a kick out of people suggesting downloading an app when the problem is insuffient storage and you can't download anything because of INSUFFIENT STORAGE.

The only solution is to factory reset and even that doesn't work when you start up again and everything is restored presumably from Google Servers.

I have done factory resets and cannot get my tablet back to factory out of the box condition. You can still use it but cannot download anything.

It can also be used for cutting onions and tomatoes.

Comment: Also can't root because the device is not being recognized by your desktop computer.Android devices are sent to test us.